# can you assign a list to threading.local() in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

can you assign a list to threading.local() in multi-threading?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to create a thread-local list?

Comment: yes, is this possible?

Comment: You can't assign anything to any function or method call. I don't understand what you're actually trying to ask about, but it seems that your understanding of the word "assign" is incorrect.

Comment: I have a function which creates a list to begin with and does subsequent functioning irrelevant to this topic. This function is a target for 'threading.Thread()'. The list needs to be unique to every thread as the values in the list will be different for every thread(since there are different parameters attached to each thread. Is it possible to make the list unique to every thread so the threads do not change the same list? - or will the list be unique anyways since it is created in the function that the 'threading.Thread()' is calling?

Comment: Something like `local().yourList=[1,2,3]` should work